# inline-block img elemets have a gap when start a new line?

Tags: html, css

when I  display img inline-block.but there is a gap between the first line and the second !! below is the sample, picture1 and picture3 have a gap?I dont't want the gap..so help me..

```css
img {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  border:5px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<img alt="picture1"/><img alt="picture2"/><img alt="picture3"/><img alt="picture4"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images make a gap by default, you can fix that using `vertical-align`

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 5px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/opz672zn/

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` may help you to fix the issue.

```css
img {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#ccc;
  border:5px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0px;
  vertical-align: top; <!--Added-->
}
```

```html
<img alt="picture1"/><img alt="picture2"/><img alt="picture3"/><img alt="picture4"/>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/161mbxfn/)